# Error setting up Android USB debugging on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: adb, linux, usb-debugging

I have an Android phone from LG, and I want to use it for USB debugging. I followed the following steps:

1. Enabled usb debugging in developers option on phone.
2. After connecting to PC, phone shows as "Usb debugging connected". I verified the same by running `lsusb` on Ubuntu 14.10. It shows the following result:

   ```
   Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1004:633e LG Electronics, Inc.
   ```
3. Then I followed steps given in https://developer.android.com, to setup hardware device.

   - Log in as root and create this file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`.
   - Use this format to add each vendor to the file:

     ```
     SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
     ```
   - Now execute: `chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`
4. After that I rebooted the computer.
5. Now when I try to check device list in adb by command `./adb devices`, it does not show the device listed.

Can anybody please help? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does it show the USB debug option to be activated in you status bar?

Comment: I didn't have to do all this. I'm on Arch so it may be a bit different for some reason, though it shouldn't really be. I installed [android-tools](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/android-tools/), enabled USB debugging on my phone and ran"adb devices" and my device showed up. I tehn ran "adb reboot bootloader" and all that stuff worked perfectly. For fastboot however I needed to be root user. This is how easy it is supposed to be in Linux because of inbuilt drivers. However I haven't tried on an LG phone and there may be some device specific steps you've missed.

Comment: In fact you could try this on a windows VM if all else fails. I needed this for the MI unlock tool when trying to root a MI device.

Answer (score 0):

- Try running commands as **root** from your adb folder:

`sudo ./adb kill-server;
sudo ./adb start-server;
sudo ./adb devices`

Answer (score 0):

On the device, **change USB connection mode** from MTP **to PTP**.

Credit/source: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=183642

Worked for an LG G Pad 10.1 (V700).